# Cannot create table errno : 150 on Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1005

i get another errno 150 on mysql. i already look at table engine, column type, but no luck, its nothing wrong in my view.

where im going wrong this time?

i get error when creating tag table that relate to image_tag and tag_lang.

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ratna`.`image_tag`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ratna`.`image_tag` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ratna`.`image_tag` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `tag` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `tag`) ,
  INDEX `image_fk` (`id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `image_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id` )
    REFERENCES `ratna`.`image` (`id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ratna`.`tag_lang`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ratna`.`tag_lang` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ratna`.`tag_lang` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `lang` INT(20) NOT NULL ,
  `tag_desc` VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `lang`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ratna`.`tag`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ratna`.`tag` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ratna`.`tag` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL ,
  `seq` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `image_tag_fk` (`id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `tag_lang` (`id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `image_tag_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id` )
    REFERENCES `ratna`.`image_tag` (`tag` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `tag_lang`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id` )
    REFERENCES `ratna`.`tag_lang` (`id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 13
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
    REFERENCES `ratna`.`image_tag` (`tag` )
```

is not valid, because `image_tag` does not have any index that begins with `tag`. As explained [in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> `InnoDB` permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are listed as the *first* columns in the same order.

("The referenced table" in this case is `image_tag`, and "the referenced columns" are just `tag`.)

Comment: im lost, is that mean i need to add index on `tag` at table `image_tag` ?

Comment: It means that you're trying to define a foreign-key that references `image_tag(tag)` without having an index on `image_tag(tag)`. So, *either* you need to give up on having the foreign-key, *or* you need to change its definition in some way, *or* you need to add an index on `image_tag(tag)` or `image_tag(tag,...)`. Without knowing more about your application, I can't tell you which of those is the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

First google result for mysql error 150 shows:

> If you re-create a table that was dropped, it must have a definition that conforms to the foreign key constraints referencing it. It must have the right column names and types, and it must have indexes on the referenced keys, as stated earlier. If these are not satisfied, MySQL returns error number 1005 and refers to error 150 in the error message.
>
> If MySQL reports an error number 1005 from a CREATE TABLE statement, and the error message refers to error 150, table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed. Similarly, if an ALTER TABLE fails and it refers to error 150, that means a foreign key definition would be incorrectly formed for the altered table. You can use SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS to display a detailed explanation of the most recent InnoDB foreign key error in the server.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: i get this. 
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.

Comment: is that mean, i cannot reference primary key to other table?

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was issue of

> foreign key (table_column_name_in_smaller_case) references
>   primary_key_table_in_upper_case (table_column_name_in_smaller_case)

since my primary key table is in Lower case, i changed this upper foreign key reference  from

> ***primary_key_table_in_upper_case***

to

> ***primary_key_table_in_lower_case***

and it worked